# How can I post different articles on different pages on a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

For exemple, if my website has a page named "Gadget" I would like to post things about gadgets on it and on another page like "Cars" i would like to post things about cars.

Comment: Belongs to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create categories and when posting an article, assign a category to it. In your pages display the posts from a certain category. You can also use tags to separate your articles.